# Cancel viewModelScope and re-use it later on

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using `Coroutines` for dealing with async jobs:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    val userResponse = getUsers() //suspendable function 
}
```

What I want to do is stop all existing/ongoing coroutine jobs. Idea is that I click on different tabs. If `getUsers()` takes up to 5 seconds and user clicks from User tab to Job tab, I want that existing API call is stopped and response is not observed.

I tried to do `viewModelScope.cancel()`, but that seems not to be working.

Question is - how to cancel existing jobs on button click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define a reusable `Job` like following in the `ViewModel` class:

```
private var job = Job()
    get() {
        if (field.isCancelled) field = Job()
        return field
    }
```

Pass it to all of launch coroutine builders as the parent `Job`:

```
viewModelScope.launch(job) {
    val userResponse = getUsers()
}

viewModelScope.launch(job) {
    // some other work
}

...
```

On button click, just cancel the parent job:

```
fun cancelAll() {
    job.cancel()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get its `Job` through its `CouroutineContext` like this:

```
viewModelScope.coroutineContext[Job]
```

To stop all existing/ongoing coroutine jobs you can call its `cancel` method:

```
viewModelScope.coroutineContext[Job]?.cancel()
```

If you need to start other coroutines eventually then call its `cancelChildren` method instead:

```
viewModelScope.coroutineContext[Job]?.cancelChildren()
```